# What is mongo status monitor HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, monitor

I am pretty much a nodejs and mongodb newbie, please be gentle. I am working on a nodejs app for a couple of weeks now and everything is as expected. Suddenly, today I notice that there are HTTP requests almost every second from within the server that:

```
req.host:   undefined
req.ip:     undefined
req.url:    /status?mongo=1
req.agent:  HTTP-Monitor/1.1
```

What are all these monitor requests about? Thanks!

Comment: do you have `net.http.enabled` set to `true` in your config?

Comment: I have this in app.js: app.enable('trust proxy');

Comment: I am on a SmartOS machine from Joyent which has mongodb preinstalled. Where do I look for the config?